# a button click on one button in a jframe doesnt loads/shows up another jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I have been working on swings framework in which there is a card layout panel in mainframe.

I have a total of 20 jpanels added to my card layout panel.Among these 20 panels,there are 3 panels which consist of a button.clicking on this button loads up another jframe. When I run this GUI using IDE, it works perfectly, but, when I run jar file, it doesn't shows up the frames when clicked on button in two of the three cases.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFrame f11=new JFrame("DEADLOCK SIMULATION-1");
    f11.add(new puzzle6());
    f11.setSize(1100,620);
    f11.setLocation(0,40);
    f11.setVisible(true);
}
```

code for other two buttons is also similar except that i have added puzzle7 and puzzle8 panels in those jframes.

This is the code I am using for buttonlistener. This button loads up the new jframe only in one case and doesnt shows up frame in other two cases.Each java file which I have added in these three new jframes extends jpanel.The problem arises only when I run jar file, but works perfectly with IDE.

Comment: show us your code containing actionPerformed() method

Comment: What's the `puzzle6` here?

Comment: puzzle 6,puzzle 7 and puzzle 8 are respectively snake,breakout and pacman games java classes each extending jpanel.This work fine when i run my GUI using IDE.Problem arises only in case of jar file.When i run it using jar file,pacman loads up but snake and breakout frames dont load/show up.The code i am using for each of these jpanels is exactly similar except that i am adding different java classes(puzzle6,puzzle6,puzzle8) in different jpanels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your events? using a Listener Class?